# blueimp Gallery JS initialization isuses

Tags: javascript, jquery, gallery, blueimp

I'm having trouble getting the gallery to display it's slides. The thumbnails work, just the actual images them selves do not and they come up as error slides.

I have other galleries working fine, and it works great using the light box but when I'm trying to execute it via java-script I run into this problem of no actual slides.

I'm trying to build a gallery via java-script and have some buttons launch each gallery.

This is the java-script I'm running to build the gallery.

```
function gallery01() {
blueimp.Gallery([
    {
        title: 'AR Ref[04-01]',
        href: './clients/liam_neeson/gallery/beijing_WV1_2008194_lrg.jpg',
        type: 'image/jpeg',
        thumbnail: './clients/liam_neeson/gallery/thumbnails/beijing_WV1_2008194_lrg.jpg'
    },
    {
        title: 'AR Ref[04-02]',
        href: './clients/liam_neeson/gallery/iwm-q_107237.jpg',
        type: 'image/jpeg',
        thumbnail: './clients/liam_neeson/gallery/thumbnails/iwm-q_107237.jpg'
    },
    {
        title: 'AR Ref[04-03]',
        href: './clients/liam_neeson/gallery/Mohne-dam-breached.jpg',
        type: 'image/jpeg',
        thumbnail: './clients/liam_neeson/gallery/thumbnails/Mohne-dam-breached.jpg'
    },
    {
        title: 'AR Ref[04-04]',
        href: './clients/liam_neeson/gallery/Passchendaele1916.jpg',
        type: 'image/jpeg',
        thumbnail: './clients/liam_neeson/gallery/thumbnails/Passchendaele1916.jpg'
    }
]);}
```

Here is my button that launches builds and launches the gallery.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("#gallery").click(gallery01);
});
```

Then I'm using a simple button (to test) to ensure this works.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" id="gallery01">
    Launch demo gallery
</button>
```

All help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you do **not** import both the JavaScript and jQuery libraries. These will conflict with your website and make the results unpredictable.